# Border Color Displaying Incorrectly in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, border

I have an issue where Firefox is failing to render the correct color of a border, whereas a browser like chrome succeeds. I am hoping to draw a dark purple color, but instead I am rendering a light pink. Here is the code that prepared to draw the border:

```
<div class="comments-list " class="" ng-click="writeGrapeComment(grape, $index)" style="background: rgba(44,62,80,0.0);border-left-style: outset;border-color: #9B59B6;width:100%;border-width:20px;padding:0px 25px 5px 25px;">
```

The CSS for the comments-list class is as follows:

```
.comments-list{
background:rgba(44,62,80,0.5);
padding:25px;
}
```

What is also vaguely disturbing is the following: I can set the border color to be pure black using the hex #000000. Yet this also does not render as a black color in Firefox! Instead it appears as a muddy beige. I would be grateful for any help I can get in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "border-left-style: solid;" instead of "border-left-style: outset;" this will work be fine..

Comment: Jeez, didn't even noticed the outset value :D

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities :

- You applied a `-moz-opacity` to a parent element
- Your Firefox color profile has been modified. Please see this link http://cameratico.com/guides/firefox-color-management/, and set all values to default ones. Alternatively, you maybe have installed a plug-in that modified your color profile, like this one : https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/color-management/

Comment: It seems to me that if I had set a moz-opacity property, then the border would display as transparent to some extent. However, it is not transparent -- it is fully opaque. Therefore, I doubt that the first possibility is the root cause of the issue. I will explore your other recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solutions apply to the situation, I've found that when all else fails, using:

-moz-border-top-colors: inherit; 
-moz-border-right-colors: inherit; 
-moz-border-bottom-colors: inherit; 
-moz-border-left-colors: inherit;

will work.