# Firefox userChrome border color incorrect on mac

Tags: css, firefox, colors, customization

I use Firefox on my mac and my pc, and I have the same userChrome for both of them to set the selected tab color and the selected search bar color to orange (as well as some other stuff). The userChrome on my pc functions perfectly fine, however on my mac the selected search bar displays as pink instead of orange. I don't do much with code so it's entirely possible I'm doing this the complete wrong way.

Pictures: On my [pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQbfu.png) (what I want it to look like) vs. on my [mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpTUV.png)

userChrome.css (same for both mac and pc):

```
    :root:-moz-lwtheme-brighttext {
    --orange-color: #F7630C;
}

    /* Orange selected tab color */
    .tab-line[selected="true"] {
    background-color: var(--orange-color) !important;
}

    /* Orange selected url bar */
    #urlbar[focused="true"] {
    border-color: var(--orange-color) !important;
}
```

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998960/border-color-displaying-incorrectly-in-firefox) but could not seem to get it to display properly. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS that color in Firefox is controlled by the operating system. To change it, click the Apple logo in the menu, System Preferences, and General. What you select as the "Accent color" will be what Firefox uses there.
Be aware it changes the color of buttons and highlights in menus too.